# Retrieving data from sqlite on the basis of date

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I am retrieving data from Sqlite database using the following query in c#

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
```

It works fine. But I want to retrieve data on the basis of date like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date=09-09-2013
```

But it do not works for me because Sqlite date representation is not in this date format.
What i want to ask is that is there any method by which Sqlite data can be retrieved on the basis of user date and time like mentioned in above query and how can I represent date and time of Sqlite database in user readable format.

Comment: You may want to search for more this `strftime` in sqlite.

Comment: Use a parameterized query.

Comment: `09-09-2013` are three numbers subtracted from each other. Maybe you wanted to use the string `'09-09-2013'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parameterized query would free your code from the formatting required for date, strings and decimals by various database engines

```
using (SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    con.Open();
    string commandText =  "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date=@dt";
    using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(commandText, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", yourDateVariable)
        SqliteReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // Extract your data from the reader here
            .....
        }
    }             
}
```

The point of this example is to show how to build a parameterized query. In this way you pass the value of your datetime variable to the framework of Sqlite engine that knows better how to format a date for the underlying system.

In the `commandText` variable the actual formatted value for the date is taken by the placeholder `@dt`, then add, to the SqliteCommand Parameters collection, a parameter with the same name of the placeholder and the value from your date variable.